# How to translate language to whole document using VBA in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I record a macro and perform all the click to translate a document, that is, Review->Transalte->Translate Document, then choose the language and finally translate, not a single line of code was recorded.

I need to programmatically execute this functionality on many documents. How can we accomplish this?

Comment: I believe (vaguely recalling a discussion with Microsoft dev team, years ago when the Research task pane was introduced) that this is not exposed in the Word object model. As, indeed, nothing that runs in the **Research** task pane is exposed. The translation feature (as well as the other things the pane is used for) connects to an outside service. The only thing that can be "touched" using the object model is the task pane (show it, for example). But nothing in the task pane is exposed.

Comment: Theoretically, you could write code to connect with an outside service and provide your own translation "assistant", but there's no way to leverage what's built into the Word application.